# Devemos remover meta tags?

Tags: debate, tags, edição

Foi [criada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3963) a tag [boas-práticas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boas-pr%c3%a1ticas), que é uma das meta-tags criticadas no artigo *[The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)*, de Jeff Atwood (um dos criadores do Stack Overflow). Uma boa definição de meta-tag [apareceu no meta do site sobre culinária](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/please-zap-the-meta-tags-and-dependent-tags), e é citada pelo Jeff Atwood no artigo:

> O motivo das meta-tags serem um problema é que elas não descrevem o conteúdo da pergunta. Eles descrevem algum outro aspecto da pergunta, como o grau de conhecimento do autor, sua motivação para perguntar, ou de que "tipo" de pergunta se trata (enquete, como fazer x, etc.)

O que vocês acham desse tipo de tag, que foi banido do SO há alguns anos? Devemos usá-las aqui? Acham que são úteis? Acham que causam ruído? Por quê?

Comment: Pergunta bônus: devemos usar [meta-tag:meta-tag] para perguntas no meta sobre meta-tags, ou para perguntas sobre as tags usadas no meta?

Comment: Vi mais duas meta tags hoje: `refatoração` e `estilo-de-codificação`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4990/refatoracao-quando-um-metodo-e-grande-demais

Comment: Tem uma coisa boa em ter meta-tags. Eles podem funcionar como *honeypot* para pergunta ruim </sarcasmo>

Comment: Na sua opinião, "revisão-de-código" é uma meta-tag? Ao fazer [uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5774/215) hoje criei essa tag, mas depois lembrei desse post e fiquei na dúvida se deveria ou não tê-lo feito...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu considero meta-tag sim. Se esse é um dos tópicos aceitos (e por enquanto é), não vejo motivo para precisar "carimbar" a pergunta com essa informação. Mas essa é só a minha opinião.

Comment: Depois de ler isto tudo (pergunta e respostas), acho que a questão das meta-tags está longe de ficar resolvida... muita opinião divergente, mas vejo também alguma aversão a meta-tags! Pessoalmente vejo a sua mais valia, mesmo que o Jeff não a veja... Mas concordo que se a plataforma não prevê meta-tags nem tem ferramentas para lidar com elas, é complicado... acaba por ser como o conteúdo das perguntas onde num site sobre problemas práticos a serem resolvidos nem precisamos de código na pergunta para a colocar :P Irei colocar uma resposta mas preciso refletir para organizar ideias!

Answer (score 12):

Acho que para discutir meta-tags basta o marcador `debate`. Já o marcador mencionado, acredito que deva ser eliminado.

Boas práticas variam de tecnologia para tecnologia. Se quero perguntar sobre boas práticas em uma tecnologia específica, uso o marcador daquela tecnologia, e isso é suficiente.

Já o marcador `boas práticas` não se sustenta por si só, como descrito no texto citado.

Acho que a mesma filosofia se aplica a qualquer marcador. Se ele for capaz de identificar o assunto da pergunta por si só, é válido. Caso contrário, é apenas ruído.

Comment: Sua opinião vale para todas as meta-tags, ou somente neste caso específico?

Comment: @bfavaretto vale para todas as tags. Editei a resposta para refletir isso.

Answer (score 8):

Meta-tags seriam úteis se o SE funcionasse de outra forma. Hoje não há nenhuma razão para usar meta-tags.

Sempre que uma pergunta **precisa** de uma meta-tag, ela tem algum problema e provavelmente deverá ser fechada ou até mesmo excluída.

Claro que em alguns casos está usando uma meta-tag como um acessório desnecessário. Aí apenas deve-se remover a tag.

`boas-praticas`, `aprendizagem`, `iniciantes`, `tutorial`, `recomendação`, `subjetivo`, `conceitual` pra mim são meta-tags. Tem outras que são próximas disso pela sua amplitude: `web`, `sistema`, `app`, etc.

Para quem não sabe, meta-tags não podem ser usadas sozinhas para dizer sobre o que está falando.

Tem pergunta que chegou ao ponto de usar uma meta-tag e ficar difícil usar outra para dar mais contexto.

Eu concordo com a resposta do Renan (a parte que ele responde a pergunta) que se a tag pode ser usada isoladamente, ela é válida. Acrescento que aí ela provavelmente não é uma meta-tag.

Mas nem sempre o critério de poder isoladamente é claro para todos. Muitos dirão que dá pra usar só `boas-práticas` em uma pergunta. O que eu discordo.

Em alguns casos tags legítimas são usadas como meta-tags também. Precisamos ficar atento a isso.

E há casos em que a pessoa usa tags que não fazem parte do problema, talvez só para ter mais visibilidade. Mas esse é outro problema.

Meta-tags incentivam perguntas ruins, principalmente nos casos em que ela seja necessária para a pergunta. E nos outros casos, onde seu uso seja desnecessário, não há porque usar algo sem necessidade.

Não vejo razão para tentarmos algo diferente aqui. Não consigo ver benefício. Gosto de experimentar algo novo quando ele pode trazer benefício. Mas estou aberto para um bom argumento para o uso delas.

Answer (score 8):

> Alerta de "Má Prática" adiante: Estou dando uma opinião baseada na experiência ;)

Boas práticas, na minha humilde experiência dos últimos 25 anos com tecnologia (ok, é um tempinho já, mas é só de uma pessoa, então cada um pese como achar que deve), é um termo que geralmente está associado à opinião pessoal disfarçada de argumento técnico, e também generalização.

Os bons programadores usam a técnica adequada conforme a situação, e a "boa prática" muda muito conforme o caso.

Um possível argumento para considerar algo "boa prática" seria orientar os novatos que não tem domínio do que estão fazendo, mas isso é apenas uma ilusão, pois a falta de domínio impede de discernir se aquilo é bom ou não.

- É boa prática evitar *goto* ? Claro que não, depende de cada caso. Pode ser e pode não ser, e quem defende qualquer extremo realmente não tem domínio sobre o assunto.
- É boa prática usar sempre { } nos *ifs* ? Mesma coisa. Depende do caso.
- É boa prática dar escape em strings pra evitar injeção de SQL? NÃO! ISSO NÃO É BOA PRÁTICA! Isso é REQUISITO se os dados estão sujeitos à interferência de terceiros. Percebe que se você analisa o que é correto ou não, não sobra espaço pra algo ser chamado de "boa prática"?

Se algo pode ser chamado apenas de "Boa prática", e não de correto ou não, melhor ou pior, por razão lógica, e aplicada a um caso específico, me desculpe. Me parece opinião pessoal disfarçada de resposta técnica. (Assim como chamar gambiarra de reparo técnico). Ao invés de dizer que é boa prática, diga que "na falta de mais informações, é preferencial que se faça assim", e explique seus motivos.

Ouvir o termo já me dá uma impressão ruim, saber que há uma tag pra isso, nem me fale então.

Answer (score 4):

Acho que é uma boa prática eliminarmos as meta-tags ;-)

Claro que eu só sei disso agora, que li os links citados na pergunta, caso contrário não teria criado a tag, rs..

Mas talvez essa tag veio em bom momento já que levantaram a discussão do que são tags boas e tags ruins, visto que eu já vi muita tag ruim por aí, por exemplo [`aprendizagem`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aprendizagem) e [`aprendizagem-programação`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aprendizagem-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)