# Devemos remover uso tags do tipo nome de empresas?

Tags: debate

Atualmente temos tags que são apenas nomes de empresas.

Na minha opinião, estas tags não ajudam em nada. Seria muito melhor que as tags fossem um a tag de um serviço, api ou produto da empresa.

O que vamos fazer sobre isso?

Estou listando algumas tags aqui neste sentido:

- [apple](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) - 33;
- [microsoft](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) - 14;
- [ibm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) - 2;
- [intel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intel) - 12;
- [embarcadero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embarcadero) - 10;
- [google](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) - 171

Como podem ver, não há tantas perguntas assim em cada tag. Mas isso pode mudar logo, com o crescimento do site. No SOen, estão tendo um grande trabalho para fazer exatamente isso agora.
Veja por exemplo a wiki da tag [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apple/info) lá, que diz em parte:

> THIS TAG IS ACTIVELY BEING REMOVED! Consider using [ios] or [osx], which are specific environments to develop for.

<sub>Apesar de mais antiga, esta foi fechada como duplicata pelo fato de a outra ser mais abrangente, incluindo as empresas e os produtos</sub>

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/808/devemos-remover-meta-tags

Comment: Se não tem função alguma para entendimento da pergunta deve tirar sim, acredito que quase todas são inadequadas, dá pra incluir outras. Algumas o nome da empresa se confunde com o produto e pode estar errado também. Um exemplo é [tag:facebook], um contra exemplo é [tag:oracle].

Comment: Debate similar no SE e possível causa deste tipo de problema: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190916/155051

Comment: @bigown gostei do contra exemplo... não tinha pensado nisso...

Comment: As Tags não facilitam os usuários encontrarem o que buscam pelo mecanismo de busca? Qual o problema que surge ao ter-se no site Tags "demais" ou Tags "inúteis"?

Comment: @Douglas neste caso, as tags não ajudam a encontrar porque por si só estas tags não significam nada. Pior, usuários iniciantes acabam utilizando estas tags em perguntas que não são necessárias. Então no mínimo são "ruído" e podem no pior caso ser problema.

Comment: @Douglas É justamente por isso. Quanto mais tags "inúteis" ou usadas de forma "errônea", mais complicado será para alguém conseguir encontrar o que deseja por base nas tags.
Aproveitando, existe [este debate](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5314/20615) sobre esse assunto, e acho que seria bem interessante a leitura, e quem sabe a sua opinião, caso discorde de algo. :p

Comment: Do meu ponto de vista praticamente a única que "manteria" e somente em caso de compiladores (quando a pergunta se tratar de arquitetura de processadores) seria [tag:intel].

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Neste caso específico, acho que seria melhor utilizar a arquitetura como tag e não o nome da empresa que a criou. Exemplo itanium ou ia64, x86-64, etc...

Comment: @EMBarbosa melhor ainda mesmo :D

Answer (score 2):

Penso que pode remover qualquer tag descontextualizada, ou seja, independente de ser nome de empresa ou não, se a tag não é relevante com o contexto da pergunta, deve remover.

A dificuldade na limpeza é que não basta apenas remover do banco de dados com uma única query. Será necessário ter cuidado em ler o contexto de cada pergunta e por vezes até os comentários.

Além do que citaram nos comentários, por exemplo, nomes que se confundem com o produto, há termos compostos como "microsoft office", "google play", "apple pay", etc.

Comment: Talvez seja necessário criar uma "força tarefa" pra cada tag justamente pra fazer essa análise e depois, se necessário, remover a tag.