# Nós realmente precisamos da tag [apple]?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

A tag [apple](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) possui 35 perguntas, onde a maioria delas poderia ser substituida pela tag [ios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [swift](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) ou [objective-c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c).

As recomendações de uso dela não ajudam muito, só diz o que é a Apple.

Precisamos mesmo dessa tag?

Comment: De repente para coisas específicas da plataforma Apple, como fazer a APN funcionar para enviar mensagens?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado no SOen ele usam uma tag propria para esta tecnologia especifica: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications, aqui usamos no singular, mas é basicamente a mesma: [tag:apple-push-notification]

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento essa tag eu não conhecia, bom saber!

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5984/2652

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Algumas tags com problemas semelhantes, que foram citadas no Meta, relativamente tem algo que dá pra dizer que tinha utilidade, mas esta tag [apple](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) ao meu ver entra nos que não tem "objetivo" real, ou seja ela pode ser:

- redundante
- irrelevante

Claro que isto é como eu vejo, no entanto gostaria que vocês se atentassem a mesma tag no SOen:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apple
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apple/info

Ela **não** existe, no passado na verdade creio que ela tenha existido (até 2016), mas lá eles perceberam que talvez ela fosse desnecessária, vejam esta postagem:

- [**Should we burninate the [Apple] tag?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333833/1518921)

Eu entendo tanto quanto muitos aqui, que nós não somos o SOen, somos outra comunidade, mas nada nos impede de **aproveitar** ideias/sugestões, ainda mais vindo de uma comunidade maior.

O outro motivo, também do meu ponto de vista, é que esta tag nos faz associar a empresa e não a tecnologia.

Então eu pessoalmente sou a favor de remover a tag [apple](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple).

Comment: Completamente a favor! -> https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5984/2652

Comment: @EMBarbosa eu nem lembrava, é praticamente dup, vou marcar ;) Obrigado